# discord.py How can I extract all channels in the category I specified?

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@commands.command()
async def c(self, ctx):
   category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, id=941749835328012328) 
   #Get the category with id I specified.
   channels = category.channels 
   #lists the channels in the category, that are at top of output
   print(channels)
   ids = discord.utils.get(category.text_channels)
   #gets channels from the list, but gets one
   print(ids)
```

when i use this command the output is like this:

```
[<TextChannel id=941749921005056060 name='test-channel' position=1 nsfw=False news=False category_id=941749835328012328>, <TextChannel id=943971117717160007 name='test-channel2' position=9 nsfw=False news=False category_id=941749835328012328>]

test-channel
```

but i want to extract it in `test-channel2` how can i do?

Comment: What do you mean by "extract all channels"? `category.channels` should be a list of the channel objects. Not the ids (but you can get one using `channels[...].id`). Also your `get` does nothing, you need to give it some kind of attribute to get to make it work.

Comment: i have edited the code, I have entered the description, as I said, there is a list of channels (top of output), but it only takes one channel from the list.

Comment: Seems to be working as intended. What do you mean by "extract `test-channel2`"? Is it something like `channels[2]`?

Comment: There are 2 channels in category `test-channel` and `test-channel2` (you can see their names and ids in top output). I want to extract both channels from top output in the `ids` section, but one channel is extract `test-channel` and the other is not extract `test-channel2` channel.

Comment: Then you get `channels[1]`. The `test-channel2` is the element at index1 in the list.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify a channel ID instead of an object name. You could also try using the method get_object_by_name() as well.

Here's what you'd end up with if you used the second option:

```
@commands.command()

async def c(self, ctx): category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, id=941749835328012328) channels = category.channels print(channels) ids = discord.utils.get(category.text_channels) print(ids) for channel in channels: channel.edit(f"This is a text channel") await channel.join()
```

Note that using the method "async" will cause your code to pause while Discord runs the command.

Comment: That's not exactly what I want to do. I can extract the id of the channel with `print(ids.id)` but it extract the first channel in the category, not other channel.

Comment: Please stop posting long python code fragments entirely on a single line.

Comment: "using the method "async" will cause your code to pause" In fact, the opposite is true. Non-async calls will block your code.